# Override headerCellTemplate of all columns in angular-ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am creating a directive on top of angular-ui-grid and I want to modify the default header cell template. I want to override headerCellTemplate of all columns without setting it for each column individually.

Looping through columnDefs and adding headerCellTemplate for each one is not possible because my columns change dynamically.

Any solution is highly appreciated.